# Makefile with a remote URL dependency

Tags: makefile

I know a network dependent makefile is poor form, so please don't lecture me.

I have a Makefile where I want to grab the latest copy of some tweets for example, as network efficiently as possible is a plus.

```
webconverger.txt:
     wget http://greptweet.com/u/webconverger/webconverger.txt -O webconverger.txt
```

However `make` obviously thinks the file is upto date once running it. Are there hack to put in the dependency section to do a `wget -q -N` to see if indeed webconverger.txt is upto date?

Answer (score 0):

```
refresh:
    wget -q -N http://greptweet.com/u/webconverger/webconverger.txt -O webconverger.txt

all: refresh webconverger.txt
```

Comment: `WARNING: timestamping does nothing in combination with -O. See the manual for details.`